# on("click", foo) and on("touchstart", foo) causing strange issues in Android vs iPhone

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-on

In the script below, you'll find both "click" and "touchstart" event below.  Orignally it was "click" event until we discovered that iPhone and iPad don't work because it required "touchstart" to work.

So, I included both of them so it would work for iPhone/iPad.

Then I run into Android issue where both "click" and "touchstart" get fired, leading to 2 times execution.

So, what's the recommened workaround to this issues for both iPhone and Android?

```
    //Saved Vehicle - Button...
    $(document).on('click touchstart', 'div[id^=RecordViewSheet]', function () {
        var dataVin = $(this).attr("data-vin");
        var dataStockNumber = $(this).attr("data-stock-number");

        ftnThrobblerAnimationBegin3().done(function () {
            httpFormSubmissionPostMethod("InspectionSheet.cshtml", "formStockNumber=" + dataStockNumber + "&formVin=" + dataVin);

            ftnThrobblerAnimationEnd3();
        });
    });
```

Comment: you dont need a touchstart event. you can use css "cursor: pointer" on the element you want to click and it will work. It's a known bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we tackled similar problem in our project was like this

```
function isMobile(){
    if(typeof window.orientation !== 'undefined') return true;
    return false;
}

var EVENT_CONFIG = {
    CLICK: isMobile()?'touchstart':'click'
}
```

and in your event assignment

```
$(document).on(EVENT_CONFIG.CLICK, 'div[id^=RecordViewSheet]', function () {
```

Explanation on the `isMobile` function.

Desktop browsers do not support `orientation` so that is how we detect if the current browser is that of desktop or of mobile.

If `window.orientation` is `undefined` then it is a desktop browser and won't support touch events.

If not, then use only touch events. You determine that in `EVENT_CONFIG`

Comment: Sorry but the orientation is an very outdated way to determine what kind of device people are using. There are several problems with this way nowadays. Rather use matchMedia to check for screen sizes.. Or/And userAgents can be considered. A combination would probably give the best result for differing devices. In this case the 'click' event is enough. It's just an iOS bug that it's not working unless you set a css cursor:pointer property